# Can an attribute applied to a method check the return value of that method?

Tags: c#, attributes

In C#, I have a method that retrieves and returns a value. It basically wraps a call to someone else's method.

```
public Thing GetFoo()
{
    return GetThingFromSource("foo");  // This is someone else's method...
}
```

I have a bunch of these methods. `GetFoo` might be called all over the place, and it's centralized to avoid scattered references to the string "foo" which could change at some point in the future.

I do this model for a lot of different methods. In each case, the thing that is returned needs to not be null.

So I need to do this:

```
public Thing GetFoo()
{
    var thing = GetThingFromSource("foo");
    Assert.IsNotNull(thing, "Thing was null");
    return thing;
}
```

This seems repetitive. I would love to see something like this:

```
[EnsureReturnValueNotNull("OMG, thing was null!!!!")]
public Thing GetFoo()
{
    return GetThingFromSource("foo");
}
```

Does such a thing exist?  How would I write such a thing?  I'm thinking something along the lines of Python's method decorators -- something that "wraps" the method.  Or even and weird event-type thing, where it throws after the method runs and checks the return value.

I might be reaching here, but it seems handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 'plain' c# there is no such thing. Attributes don't actually do anything. You can make it work if you use GetFoo in some kind of framework (MVC routing, unittesting, etc) in which case you could check attributes and apply their meaning.

One way to make it work is to use Postsharp (https://www.postsharp.net/) Then it would look something like this

```
[Serializable]
public class EnsureReturnValueNotNullAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        base.OnInvoke(args);

        if (args.ReturnValue == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "OMG, thing was null!!!!");

        }
    }
}
```

The term you are looking for here is Aspect Oriented Programming. There are a few other frameworks around but i havn't found anything that beats postsharp.